# Viewing frequency of multiple values in grouped Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with three column variables A,B,C, taking numeric values in {1,2}, {6,7}, and {11,12}. I would like to see the following. For what fraction of possible observed pairs (A,B) do we have both [observations for which C=11 and observations for which C=12].

I start by entering the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2], "B": [6,7,7,6,7,6,6,6], "C": [11,12,11,11,12,12,11,12]})
--------

    A   B   C
0   1   6   11
1   2   7   12
2   1   7   11
3   1   6   11
4   2   7   12
5   1   6   12
6   1   6   11
7   2   6   12
```

Then I think I need to use `groupby`. I run

```
g = df.groupby(["A", "B"])
"g.C.value_counts()"

----------- 
A  B  C 
1  6  11    3
      12    1
   7  11    1
2  6  12    1
   7  12    2
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

This shows that we have one pair of (A,B) for which we have both a C=11 and a C=12, and 3 pairs of (A,B) for which we only have either C=11 or C=12. So I would like to make pandas tells me that we have 25% of (A,B) paris for which C takes both values and 75% for which it only takes one value.

How can I accomplish this? I would like to do so for a big data frame where I can't just eyeball it from the `value_counts`--this small dataframe is just to illustrate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass `normalize=True`

```
out = df.groupby(["A", "B"]).C.value_counts(normalize=True)
Out[791]: 
A  B  C 
1  6  11    0.75
      12    0.25
   7  11    1.00
2  6  12    1.00
   7  12    1.00
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'm looking for something slightly different. There are 4 observed pairs of (A,B): (1,6), (1,7), (2,6), (2,7). I want to know, for what fraction of those pairs do we get both values of C observed vs. only one of the possible values observed. So the answer should be that for 1/4 of the observed (A,B) pairs (namely, (1,6)) we get both C values, and for 3/4 we get only one C value. Your answer tells me the percentage within a particular (A,B) pair. I'm looking for percentages across (A,B) pairs.